# Use templates to bind a class method to a specific prototype

Tags: c++, templates

I'm looking for a way to bind functions and class methods to a specific prototype.

Let's say I want to bind functions and class methods with this prototype

```
int (float)
```

to this one

```
void ()
```

Here is my code

```
class Toto
{
public:
    int test(float f) { std::cout << "Toto::test " << f << std::endl; return 0; }
} toto;

int test(float f)
{
    std::cout << "test " << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template <typename T, T t>
void func()
{
    t(4.0f);
}

template <typename T>
void func<int (T::*)(float), int (T::*method)(float)>()
{
    toto::*method(5.0f);
}

auto    main(int, char**) -> int
{
    func<int(*)(float), &test>();
    func<void (Toto::*)(float), &Toto::test>();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

The function binding works properly, but the method one seems to have some syntax issues that I don't get. g++ gives me this error :

```
src/main.cpp:28:6: error: parse error in template argument list
src/main.cpp:28:55: error: function template partial specialization ‘func<int (T::*)(float), <expression error> >’ is not allowed
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You cannot partial specialize template function.

Comment: `auto main(int, char**) -> int` - come on, really...?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot partial specialize template function, but you can for class/struct:

```
namespace details
{
    template <typename T, T t>
    struct func_impl
    {
        void operator () () const { t(4.0f); }
    };

    template <typename T, int (T::*method)(float)>
    struct func_impl<int (T::*)(float), method>
    {
        void operator () () const { (toto.*method)(5.0f); }
    };

}   

template <typename T, T t>
void func()
{
    details::func_impl<T, t>{}();
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/NhnPTj)